# Internet connectivity dropping intermittently on Mac 2018 Mojave

Tags: network, wifi, mojave

---

I got a new Macbook pro with the following specs:
[image]

The internet connects just fine but then drops randomly, and then reconnects randomly. It actually happens so fast.

I ran a diagnostics report, and it recommended the following:
[image]
[image]

I searched online and did this (I added both OpenDns and GoogleDNS) like so:
[image]

but the problem still persists.

What do I do?

here is my [network diagnostic report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ERHB9XwQy5Y7JnwnUnMNdI2kgFXcYbs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Same problem. Then when you click the wifi icon top right the waiting icon shows and the whole pc slows down significantly.